# How do I enforce referential integrity on a database field conditional upon another field in the referencing table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, referential-integrity

First of all, I hope whoever reads this is well at these difficult times.

I am trying to code a database using MariaDB/MySql that can manage inventory and groups of business transactions.

I have an inventory transaction category table that, believe it or not, details the name and effects of the transaction on both the quantity of hand and the total value of the quantity of each inventory item. I have an inventory transaction table that details the inventory transaction. I also plan to have several 'business transaction' tables and sub-tables: for example, sales_orders and sales_order_product_details.

I want to associate an inventory transaction category with a business transaction category so that I can test for existence of a business transaction reference that is placed in the respective field in the inventory transaction table in the respective business transaction table. I would like to do this by having 2 columns that are subject to conditional constraints: business_transaction_id and business_transaction_line_item_id.

Sorry, if the above isn't very clear. In practice: inventory is issued from store to fulfill a sales order. This is categorised as a sales_issue transaction. sales_issue transactions are associated with the sales_order and related tables. When a value is placed inside the business_transaction_id and business_transaction_line_item_id, referential integrity is enforced by checking for existence of these values in the relevant business transaction table.

Is this possible with SQL or will I have to run back-end scripts to enforce this?

Any help or advice you can give would be very helpful.

```
    CREATE TABLE inventory_transaction_categories (
      category_id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      category_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (category_name != ""),
      quantity_effect VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL CHECK (quantity_effect = "increasing" OR quantity_effect = "decreasing" OR quantity_effect = "none"),
      value_effect VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      business_transaction_table VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
      );

    CREATE TABLE inventory_transactions (
      transaction_id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      transaction_date_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
      inventory_transaction_category_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      business_transaction_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
      business_tansaction_line_item_id INT UNSIGNED,
      product_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      product_quantity INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      product_value DECIMAL (15,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      issuing_inventory_location_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      receiving_inventory_location_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL CHECK (issuing_inventory_location_id != receiving_inventory_location_id),
      CONSTRAINT product_id 
      FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product_details(product_id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_issuing_location 
      FOREIGN KEY (issuing_inventory_location_id) REFERENCES inventory_locations(inventory_location_id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_receiving_location
      FOREIGN KEY (receiving_inventory_location_id) REFERENCES inventory_locations(inventory_location_id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_tran_category 
      FOREIGN KEY (inventory_transaction_category_id) REFERENCES inventory_transaction_categories(category_id) 
      );

CREATE TABLE sales_orders (
  order_id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  date_created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  order_date DATE NOT NULL,
  order_time TIME NOT NULL,
  sales_channel_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  external_reference VARCHAR(100),
  customer_name VARCHAR(200),
  delivery_address_line_1 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  delivery_address_line_2 VARCHAR(100),
  delivery_address_line_3 VARCHAR(100),
  delivery_address_city VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  delivery_address_county VARCHAR(100),
  delivery_address_postcode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  delivery_address_country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  order_status_id INT UNSIGNED,
  courier VARCHAR(200),
  sales_channel_delivery_service VARCHAR(200),
  delivery_service_used VARCHAR(200),
  postal_tracking_number VARCHAR(50),
  products_net_total_GBP DECIMAL(15, 2) UNSIGNED,
  products_total_vat_GBP DECIMAL(15, 2) UNSIGNED,
  delivery_charge_vat_code VARCHAR(2),
  delivery_charge_net_total_GBP DECIMAL(15, 2) UNSIGNED,
  delivery_charge_total_vat_GBP DECIMAL(15, 2) UNSIGNED,
  order_net_total_GBP DECIMAL(15, 2) UNSIGNED,
  order_vat_total_GBP DECIMAL(15, 2) UNSIGNED,
  order_gross_total_GBP DECIMAL(15, 2) UNSIGNED,
  CONSTRAINT sales_channel
  FOREIGN KEY (sales_channel_id) REFERENCES sales_channels(sales_channel_id),
  CONSTRAINT vat_delivery_constraint 
  FOREIGN KEY (delivery_charge_vat_code) REFERENCES vat_rates(vat_code),
  CONSTRAINT order_status_constraint
  FOREIGN KEY (order_status_id) REFERENCES order_status_categories(order_status_id)
  );

CREATE TABLE sales_order_product_details (
  sales_order_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  line_item_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  product_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  quantity INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  product_price_GBP DECIMAL(15, 2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  discount_GBP DECIMAL (15, 2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  net_total_GBP DECIMAL(15, 2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  vat_total_GBP DECIMAL(15, 2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(sales_order_id, line_item_id),
  CONSTRAINT order_constraint
  FOREIGN KEY (sales_order_id) REFERENCES sales_orders(order_id),
  CONSTRAINT product_constraint
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product_details(product_id)
  );
```

Comment: Your example tables are complex and not to the point, so it's not easy to understand the question. However, I would say the answer is "no". Once you create foreign keys they point exactly to **one** table and they are enforced from then on. One option would be to have multiple FKs; for example if you need to point to three tables, you can have three nullable FKs, each one pointing to it's table; a CHECK constraint would enforce only one is not null at the same time.

Comment: That's understandable. I thought so. I was trying to avoid having multiple columns, but it seems it might not be possible. Running a CHECK constraint akin to that you have mentioned did cross my mind, and thanks for underlining it as possibly the best solution.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of maybe creating an order transaction in all tables with the id of 0, So, a sales order with id 0 that is not actually a sales order, which would in effect be empty and serve as nothing more than to indicate that the inventory transaction is not associated with a record from this table. I thought I could then run a check constraint that checks that only 1 column can not be of a value 0, avoiding null values as the record does not exist at all. I think I understand NULL to indicate the absence of a value in existence, but I'm open to doubting my name at the moment. Haha

Comment: Big thank you for the response and I will try to make my questions clearer and more concise in the future.